# How do you set a css class based on a select query in Sencha Touch?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have a simple select query to select DOM node:

```
var selectNode = Ext.select('.myCSSClass textarea');
```

I want to apply a css class to *textarea*.

I have tried:

```
selectNode.addCls('newClass');
```

I have also tried using Ext.ComponentQuery to select the node and it doesn't work.

I also tried using the *apply()* method:

```
Ext.apply(selectNode, {
    cls: 'newClass'
});
```

Comment: Did the answer help ? If yes accept it, if no then why ?

Comment: I couldn't get select() to work. I used the down method and it worked. selectNode.element.down('.myCSSClass textarea')

Comment: Then please edit the answer below and accept it or add you own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ext.select` returns a array of elements that respond to the CSS selector you gave.
If you want to add a CSS class to the  `class` attribute of this element you have to do this :

```
Ext.select('.css-class').elements[0].className += ' myClass'; // don't forget the space
```

Example :

[image]

Hope this helps